# ¿Cómo utilizar $sum con $match para filtros dinámicos?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Necesito realizar la suma de un campo en una colección.
He logrado realizarlo por el total, pero no puedo ni entiendo muy bien como hacerlo con parametros dinámicos.

```js
var query = {};
if (req.body.tipo_doc)  query['tipo_doc'] = req.body.tipo_doc;
if (req.query.fromDate && req.query.toDate) {
    query['fecha'] = {"$gte": req.query.fromDate, "$lte": req.query.toDate};
}
if (req.decoded.rolecode != 'ADM' && req.decoded.rolecode != 'SUP') query['pto_venta'] = req.decoded.puntoDefault;
if (!req.query.status) {
    query['status'] = 'Activa';
    query['notaCredito'] = false;
}

Factura.aggregate([{
    $match : {$and: [query]},
},{
    $group : {
        _id : null,
        total : {
            $sum : "$total"
        }
    }
}],function(err, result) {
    if (err) res.send(err);

    res.json(result); 
});
```

Sin la parte de $match funciona perfecto pero me trae todo y yo necesito filtrar por esos parámetros.

Comment: He modificado el script a esto:
    Factura.aggregate([{
     $match : {
        $and: [
            { fecha: {
                '$gte': '2017-07-01T00:00:00.000Z',
                '$lte': '2017-07-31T23:59:00.000Z'
            }},
            { status: "Activa"},
            { notaCredito: false}
        ]
     }   
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : null,
            total : {
                $sum : "$total"
            }
        }
    }],function(err, result) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(result); 
    });
Y tampoco funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a este problema.
El problema lo generaban las fechas:

Asi me quedó el script con la consulta:

```
Factura.aggregate([{
 $match : {
    $and: [
        { fecha: {
            '$gte': new Date(req.query.fromDate),
            '$lte': new Date(req.query.toDate)
        }},
        query
    ]
 }   
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : null,
        total : {
            $sum : "$total"
        }
    }
}],function(err, result) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.json(result); 
});
```

Donde query es lo mismo que antes excepto el if de las fechas porque en mi caso vienen siempre como parametros.
Espero le sirva a alguien